# mysqli UNION get data in correct column name

Tags: mysql, union

I want to get data from database with UNION , I defined link as newslink, and pic as articlepic but it show articlepic data under newslink column, how can I fix this?

```
SELECT * FROM
((SELECT date, link as newslink FROM news ORDER BY id DESC)
UNION
(SELECT date, pic as articlepic FROM article ORDER BY id DESC)) as x
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 6
```

**[Sample Data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d9ec1/6)**

I want to get articlepic data under articlepic column, and newslink under newslink column

Comment: update your question and add  your expected  result too

Comment: This seems like just a `mysql` question, `PHP` and `mysqli` are unrelated to your issue. The union can only have one name per column. You could add a third column so you know which table it came from. Like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d9ec1/12

Comment: Right you are @user3783243 and relevance (to php) can be found [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52386776/mysqli-union-get-data-in-correct-column-name#comment91718183_52386845) by the OP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you  values in different column you must add  null value in the select for not corresponding columns

```
SELECT * FROM
 ((SELECT date, link as newslink, null as articlepic 
  FROM news ORDER BY id DESC)
UNION
 (SELECT date, null, pic 
   FROM article ORDER BY id DESC)) as x
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 6
```

Comment: Well, it's perfect but how can I get it in `php` ? I mean want to echo each `articlepic` how can I echo null ?

Comment: You can take an example of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52386776/mysqli-union-get-data-in-correct-column-name/52386877#52386877 @tourtravel

Comment: you echo the content of the column name so you echo  $row['newlink'] and $row['articlepic']

Comment: if you don't want null you can also use and ifnull(your_col, 'your_value_for-nul')

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to get the different name of the column when using union in the query

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
        (
        SELECT
            DATE,
            link AS newslink,
            '-'  As articlepic         
        FROM news ORDER BY id DESC
    ) UNION (
    SELECT
        DATE,
        '-'  As newslink,         
        pic AS articlepic
    FROM article ORDER BY id DESC
)
    ) AS X
ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 6
```